# How to use only one line linux command to find the file?

Tags: linux, shell

There are 10000 files in current dir. They are named by 3 part, first is a letter. second is a date. third is some random letters. I need to find the latest file. If find more than one with the same latest date. I need the last file sorted by the alphabet.

```
example:files

d20161112lif43
x20161205flb8
c20161201lgir334
i20161205gid
```

the wanted file is x201612054lb8

Comment: to find a file by name use `find . -name "x201612054lb8"`

Comment: I don't know the exact name

Comment: Why are we only allowed one line?

Comment: I like the simple style

Comment: What if it's a choice between a simple 5-liner and a complicated one-liner?

Comment: em.. you are right

Comment: @RuslanOsmanov your code works :)

Comment: @mpez0 this doesn't sort by the date in chars 2-9, as OP asks (neither does Ruslan's)

Answer (score 3):

You can give multiple key definitions to `sort`, so:

```
ls | sort --key=1.2,1.9 --key=1.1,1.1 | tail -1
```

This sorts by chars 2-9, then by char 1, then uses `tail` to return only the last line.

Other answers are using `find` instead of `ls`. This isn't necessary unless the files are spread among subdirectories (and if they are, you'll have other issues to deal with) or if there are directories as well as files, that you want to ignore.

---

This is an easy one-liner, but it is not efficient. If you have 10,000 files, `sort` must sort a 10,000 entry list, which is quite a lot of processing.

If instead you used your favourite scripting language to do (python-ish pseudocode):

```
 latest_file = read_line
 while(current_file = read_line): 
     if(current_file > latest_file): // by your priority rules
         latest_file = current_file
 print latest_file
```

Whereas a full sort needs to have all 10,000 entries in memory, this algorithm only ever needs two entries in memory -- the current winner, and one entry that's under consideration.

---

Bonus solution, using real Python this time:

```
ls | python -c 'import fileinput; print max(fileinput.input(), key=lambda s : s[1:9] + s[0:0])'
```

(Although if you're going to break out Python, it might be time to let Python handle the directory reading, instead of building a hybrid shell/Python solution: `python -c 'import os; print max(os.listdir("."), key=lambda x : x[1:9] + x[0:0])'` -- and you're asking about shell)

Comment: FYI, in actual Python, [`max` takes a `key` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) that could be used to perform this sort of loop implicitly over an input iterable (and significantly faster).

Comment: @ShadowRanger Thanks. The resulting Python one-liner was worth adding.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this should work:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -regextype posix-extended -regex '^.*\/[a-zA-Z][0-9]{8}[^/]*$' | sort | sort -k 1.4,1.12 -n -s | tail -n 1
```

The first sort sorts alphabetically, the second sort does a stable numeric sort sorting by the date digits (making it stable preserves the original alphabetic sort when the keys match), then `tail` pulls off the final value.

The regex ensures it meets the basic criteria (letter followed by eight digits), so you don't sort and process garbage.

Comment: the result starts with ./

Comment: @user3130007: Good point, my mistake for testing with `ls` (which is a bad idea for general scripting, but convenient). Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a command like this:

```
find -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -printf '%f\n' | sort -k1.2,1.9g -k1 | tail -1
```

or, in reverse order:

```
find -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -printf '%f\n' | sort -r -k1.2,1.9g -k1 | head -1
```

Comment: This just sorts alphabetically. OP wanted to sort by the date in chars 2-9, *then* alphabetically.

Answer (score 0):

To find all files and sort them alphabetically by the current date:

`find . -name "*20161205*" | sort | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/ /g'`

`find . -name "*date*"` will grab all files in the current directory by date (excluding before and after)

`sort` it

`sed` will remove the new lines

Comment: Doesn't do what OP wants.

Comment: No? Maybe I misunderstood.  `I need to find the latest file. If find more than one with the same latest date. I need the last file sorted by the alphabet.`

Comment: @ThomasBennett: I don't think the OP knows what the latest date will be ahead of time, so you can't hard-code the date in the search.

Comment: Ah. Thanks. Is it proper to delete my answer? @ShadowRanger

Comment: Since it doesn't answer the question, sure.